# How can I do a tcp syn port scan with golang?

Tags: sockets, tcp, go, raw-sockets, port-scanning

I'm trying to write a tcp syn port scanner with golang, I found a solution in C version here: http://www.binarytides.com/tcp-syn-portscan-in-c-with-linux-sockets/

I'd like to implement it in go, how can I send a **tcp header** like this in golang:

```
//TCP Header
    tcph->source = htons ( source_port );
    tcph->dest = htons (80);
    tcph->seq = htonl(1105024978);
    tcph->ack_seq = 0;
    tcph->doff = sizeof(struct tcphdr) / 4;      //Size of tcp header
    tcph->fin=0;
    tcph->syn=1;
    tcph->rst=0;
    tcph->psh=0;
    tcph->ack=0;
    tcph->urg=0;
    tcph->window = htons ( 14600 );  // maximum allowed window size
    tcph->check = 0; //if you set a checksum to zero, your kernel's IP stack should fill in the correct checksum during transmission
    tcph->urg_ptr = 0;
```

Do I have to use syscall or cgo? I'm really appreciated if someone could help me out.

Answer (score 0):

You're going to want to use syscall. However the syscall package is not necessarily portable across different Operating Systems so if that matters to you then you'll have to write per os versions and use the file_os.go naming scheme to hold the os specific code.